# How to select current DIV ID to run Jquery with that ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML like this.

```
<div id="content"
     <div id="widget1">
       <script type='text/javascript'>
                jQuery("#widget(current)").selectme({
                Numpost:4,
                Stylepost:"papa",
                });
       </script>
     </div>
     <div id="widget89">
       <script type='text/javascript'>
                jQuery("#widget(current)").selectme({
                Numpost:7,
                Stylepost:"popo",
                });
       </script>
     </div>

     ..............
     <div id="widget(anyIndex)">.....</div>
 </div>
```

Widget ID change when I add more. For example: widget89 is set current but I don't know the index of that widget (index = 89), just sure that I am inputting Javascript/Jquery code into it. When I add new widget I will have new index, for example : widget105 or also widget200 (anyindex).

How to catch current widget whenever I add more for running Jquery inside. It means we have same thing like :

```
 <div id="widget1">
       <script type='text/javascript'>
                jQuery("#widget1").selectme({
                Numpost:4,
                Stylepost:"papa",
                });
       </script>
     </div>
     <div id="widget89">
       <script type='text/javascript'>
                jQuery("#widget89").selectme({
                Numpost:7,
                Stylepost:"popo",
                });
       </script>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [attribute-start-with-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) like,

```
jQuery( "[id^='widget']" ).selectme({
```

Or you can apply `class` for your `element` like,

```
<div class="select-me-widget">.....</div>
```

And use in `jquery` like,

```
jQuery( ".select-me-widget" ).selectme({
```